# How to avoid accepting characters inputted during a delay in loop?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a program here which reads whatever character we enter via keyboard, print it, waits for a delay period of 1 second and then repeats the whole thing.

The problem is that I don't want the characters inputted during the 1-second delay to be considered as valid input to be printed.
Only the input which are received after the 1-second delay need to be printed.

But using this code, not even a single character entered during the delay are discarded.

I tried fflush(stdin) but it still won't do. And I thought it really did clear the buffer.

Any ideas?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
void delay(int a)
{
    clock_t t=clock();
    while(clock() - t < a);
}

int main()
{
    delay(5000);
    char c;

    while(1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        while(!kbhit());
        c=getch();
        printf("\n%d %c", c, c);
        delay(1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: `fflush` is defined only for output streams. So flushing `stdin` does not do what you want. A simple approximate solution  is just to consume all the input with a `getch` loop immediately after the delay.

Comment: No solution using standard C,  Need to use implementation dependent functions.

Comment: Why would you do that? It would be extremely annoying for users.

Comment: @n.m. I am trying to make a program which will display the character entered by a user followed by a 5 second delay.  If the characters entered randomly during this delay are all considered, it is uncomfortable as it will seem to user that inputs are coming out of nowhere even when he himself had entered it during the delay.

Comment: Have you tried to use a program which behaves like that? Consider these two modes of operation: 1. All characters typed by the user will appear on screen sooner or later. 2. Some characters will appear and some will be lost; to avoid disappearing keystrokes the user should closely monitor the state of the program. If you think mode 2 is what your users want, go ahead and imolement it. I personally have no idea in what applucation it could be useful.

Comment: @n.m. It is mode 2 that I want. How can I implement it?

Comment: You have to monitor bith current time and the state of the keyboard, at the same time. Start a timer and a keyboard monitor, whatever it is on your platform. If a key is pressed before one second has passed, read the character and discard it.

Comment: I see you are using kbhit in a busy-wait loop. Consider this pseudocode: `time0=gettime(); while( true ) { time=gettime(); if (time-time0 > 1s) break; if (kbhit()) getch(); }` This should, in a horribly inefficient way, wait for 1 second while ignoring user input made during this time. Improve from here.

Comment: @kaylum How can I find the number of times getch() should be applied to ensure that all input is consumed after the delay?

Comment: The comment above by @n.m. already shows you how to do that. Just keep calling `getch` until `kbhit` returns false.